# Converting from "too" to "enough"

Tags: negation, comparative-constructions

I have this sentence:

- It is too hot to handle.

How do I rewrite it using *enough* in place of *too*? Is the following right? Is there some other possibility?

- It is not cold enough to handle.

What is the grammar behind this conversion? Is the antonym always present in the *enough* version?

PS: I learnt this a long time back at school in English grammar and remember only vaguely.

Comment: Sultan, welcome! I edited your question to replace "learnt" with "learned". I have done this because it seems that "learnt" is a rare past form of "learn"; "learned" is more common, instead.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I edited it back! There's nothing wrong with *learnt*. Okay - it's always been less popular with Americans, but ELL has no remit to encourage US usage. And usage might be [declining a bit in the UK](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learnt&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=), but it's still perfectly acceptable and current. There are plenty of questions (and answers) with glaring spelling/punctuation errors that never get fixed, so I don't think it's right to foist what's basically just a "personal preference" on others like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested sentence is definitely a good alternative. The only suggestion I might make, depending on the context, is that it may sound a bit more natural to use "cool" instead of "cold":

> It is not *cool* enough to handle.

I say this because when you refer to something that is currently hot but is losing heat over time, you say the item is "cooling". Thus, it makes sense to say something like:

> The pie on the counter is still cooling; it's not cool enough to handle.

*Cool* is more readily interpreted as "within an acceptable range" than the somewhat more extreme *cold*, which, in many cases, suggests that the object being described is cooler than you would prefer. *Cool* is (almost?) never used to mean "too cold", but *cold* certainly is, so *cool* works a little better when talking about an acceptable range of temperature, especially when contrasted with "too hot".

IMO.

**Edit:**
In addition, again depending on context, you may want to consider adding the word "yet", as in:

> It is not cool enough to handle *yet*.

This works especially well to imply that while it is still too hot *right now*, it will soon be cool enough to handle.

Comment: All the examples you give make sense to me and I wouldn't be confused to hear them. In my experience, I don't think I am very likely to call the pie just *cool*, though, unless I mean *great*. I think I usually talk about whether it has *cooled off* or *cooled down* yet: "it *hasn't cooled off enough* to handle".

Comment: Those are fine too. And yeah, I am sure no one would be *confused*, per say, by the use of "cold", it's just quite a bit less common than "cool" in my daily experience, and, *to me*, it makes more intuitive sense, but cold definitely works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

The rules about the intensifiers, too and enough, are not *too* difficult to master once learnt.

**too** + adjective

- "The questions are **too easy**, this test is boring," he said.
- She was upset because the test had been **too advanced** for her level.

auxiliary verb + not + verb/adjective + **enough**

- "The questions **aren't** difficult **enough**, this test is boring," he said.
- She was upset because the test **hadn't been** easy **enough** for her to pass.
- She **didn't** study (hard) **enough** and so she failed the test.
- They **hadn't** bought her **enough** books.

**too** + **many** + countable noun

**too** + **much** + uncountable noun

- There are **too many questions** in this test.
- There's **too much noise** in my house for me to study.

auxiliary verb + **not** + **enough** + countable and uncountable noun

- There **aren't enough questions** in this test.
- There **isn't enough silence** in my house for me to study.
- She **didn't** have **enough time** to study.

**enough** + countable/uncountable **noun** or **adjective**

And to create positive sentence so, it's not always true that "enough" follows "not".

- She answered **enough questions** correctly to narrowly pass the test.
- There is **enough time** and **silence** for her to revise.
- He is **qualified enough** to apply for university.